# peerDependencies configuration for publishable libraries with NX & Angular

Tags: angular, npm, npm-publish, nrwl, ng-packagr

I have a monorepo using NX & Angular and I am publishing some libs to NPM and i have the following scenario

```
apps
   only_App
libs
   lib_A // v1.0.0
   lib_B // v1.0.0
   lib_C // v1.0.0
```

lib_A depends on lib_B and lib_C.

In the **pre-built** package.json of `lib_A` doesn’t have any `peerDependency` and after i build it prior publishing it, automatically adds the peerDependencies like

```
// BUILT lib_A/package.json

{
...,
"peerDependencies":{
   "@myScope/lib-b": "1.0.0", //specifically that version
   "@myScope/lib-c": "1.0.0",
}
}
```

The problem is when i publish `lib_A` and use it in another project (outside NX and this repo). It will always expect me to use `lib_B` and `lib_C` **v1.0.0**,
if I make a patch in `lib_B` upgrading it to **v1.0.1**, then im forced to also rebuild `lib_A` updating the peerDependency version. publish `lib_A` and upgrade `lib_A`'s version too.

Is there a way i can configure this so when i build `lib_A` adds the `^` to my libs? i.e

```
// BUILT lib_A/package.json

{
...,
"peerDependencies":{
   "@myScope/lib-b": "^1.0.0", //automatically includes the ^ (caret)
   "@myScope/lib-c": "^1.0.0",
}
}
```

Allowing me in this way if I have a minor patch in lib_B, just to update lib_B and not lib_A as well.

So far the only “solution” is to manually copy and paste the peer dependencies generated in the *built* package.json in the **pre-built** package.json and add the `^` manually, but i know this is not scalable

Comment: running into this too - i think the only option is to script it manually as you describe

Answer (score -3):

Add `"buildableProjectDepsInPackageJsonType": "dependencies"` in your build target in your `project.json` file.

https://nx.dev/packages/js/executors/tsc#buildableprojectdepsinpackagejsontype

Comment: This is probably not desirable - peerDependencies and dependencies are semantically different.  Setting this to `dependencies` will risk a project installing your libs having multiple copies of the target dependencies installed, which can lead to lots of issues where singletons are expected.